# Como fazer a tela de game play aumentar conforme o objeto player cresce?

Tags: construct-2

Quero dizer, como fazer aquele efeito de câmera que existe no Agar.io, onde quanto mais o player aumenta de tamanho, mais a tela 'aprofunda', evitando que a imagem do player desapareça nas bordas da tela de game play?

Já tentei com o Set layout scale: (layoutscale - 0.1), modificando os valores, mas nunca dá certo. Abaixo deixo o jogo onde quero aplicar esse efeito.

Link do jogo no Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3eakunqa1vp50c/Project%20Game1.capx?dl=0